# image zoom out feature using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project in which there is an image when user clicks on image the image zoom in and when click again the image zoom out. How can I make a zoom out feature in my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/doforumda/95wqh/9/)

```
function resizeImg (img) {
    var scale = 150/100;
    var pos = $(img).offset();
    var clickX = event.pageX - pos.left;
    var clickY = event.pageY - pos.top;
    var container = $(img).parent().get(0);

    $(img).css({
        width: img.width*scale, 
        height: img.height*scale
    });

    container.scrollLeft = ($(container).width() / -2 ) + clickX * scale;
    container.scrollTop = ($(container).height() / -2 ) + clickY * scale;
}
```

Comment: you mean first click should zoom in and next should zoom out?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple images this might also help you

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95wqh/14/

JS code:

```
$('.image').on('click', function () {
    if (typeof this.toggleZoom === "undefined") this.toggleZoom = false;
    this.toggleZoom = !this.toggleZoom;
    resizeImg(this);
});

function resizeImg(img) {
    var scale = (img.toggleZoom) ? 150 / 100 : 100 / 150;
    console.log(scale);
    var pos = $(img).offset();
    var clickX = event.pageX - pos.left;
    var clickY = event.pageY - pos.top;
    var container = $(img).parent().get(0);

    $(img).css({
        width: img.width * scale,
        height: img.height * scale
    });

    container.scrollLeft = ($(container).width() / -2) + clickX * scale;
    container.scrollTop = ($(container).height() / -2) + clickY * scale;
}
```

### What I added

```
    if (typeof this.toggleZoom === "undefined") this.toggleZoom = false;
    this.toggleZoom = !this.toggleZoom;
```

and

```
    var scale = (img.toggleZoom) ? 150 / 100 : 100 / 150;
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need a lot of javascript here..just some good CSS as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/95wqh/10/

JS:

```
$('.image').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('zoom');
});
```

css:

```
#Container {
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}

.zoom{
    -webkit-transform : scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try and see if the below code helps you. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/G2hyT/)

**EDIT:** Just in-case you want to do this on multiple images in same page.

```
var zoom = "in";

$('.image').on('click', function () {
    this.zoom = (this.zoom == "in") ? "out" : "in";
    console.log(this.zoom);
    resizeImg(this);
});

function resizeImg (img) {
    var scale = 150/100;
    var pos = $(img).offset();
    var clickX = event.pageX - pos.left;
    var clickY = event.pageY - pos.top;
    var container = $(img).parent().get(0);

    if(img.zoom == "in"){
         $(img).css({
            width: img.width*scale, 
            height: img.height*scale
         });
    }
    else if (img.zoom == "out"){
        $(img).css({
            width: img.width/scale, 
            height: img.height/scale
        });
    }  
    container.scrollLeft = ($(container).width() / -2 ) + clickX * scale;
    container.scrollTop = ($(container).height() / -2 ) + clickY * scale;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/95wqh/13/)

[**DEMO Works with multiple images**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/95wqh/15/)

```
$('img').attr('zoom', 0);
$('.image').on('click', function () {
    resizeImg(this);
});

function resizeImg(img) {
    var zoom = $(img).attr('zoom');
    if (zoom == 0) {
        var scale = 150 / 100;
        var pos = $(img).offset();
        var clickX = event.pageX - pos.left;
        var clickY = event.pageY - pos.top;
        var container = $(img).parent().get(0);
        $(img).css({
            width: img.width * scale,
            height: img.height * scale
        }).attr('zoom', 1);
        container.scrollLeft = ($(container).width() / -2) + clickX * scale;
        container.scrollTop = ($(container).height() / -2) + clickY * scale;
    }else{
        $(img).attr('zoom',0).attr('style','');
    }
}
```

setting `zoom` attribute = 0 for all the images --> `$('img').attr('zoom', 0);`

if `zoom` attribute is set to `0` we will make `zoom` effect and set attribute `zoom=1`

else `zoom` attribute is set to `1` that is already zoomed we set the attribute `zoom=0` and `style` attribute is removed to get the image back to normal.