# Zoom in and out image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to zoom in and zoom out an image whenever the user click the zoom in button or the zoom out button.

The example I've took only change the width of the image, and that it's not what I really need, because the div width will be a limitation.

This is the code I used:

```
var width =  $("#imgMain").prop('width');
  var zoomincrement = width * 1/3;
  var zoom = width + zoomincrement ; 
  $("#imgMain").prop('width',zoom);
```

And this is the image:

```
 <div style="height: 500px; width: 800px; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: gray;">
   <img  id="imgMain" class="imgMain" src="image"  />
 </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285974/image-zoom-out-feature-using-javascript please look at this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/95wqh/57/ check this fiddle